# Delete rows with pandas an excessive length of a string in a field

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter

I would like to eliminate in a column in the dataframe with pandas an excessive length of a string in a field, example:

```
email,name,user
test1@hotmail.com,joe,4321
test1.test2.test3._4567865433_testqwerty@gmail.com,rey,9876
test-_2@aol.com,loy,6543
```

In short, remove in this case the field with the email that is too long.

```
email,name,user
test1@hotmail.com,joe,4321
test-_2@aol.com,loy,6543
```

Do you know a short way to do it?

Comment: what is your threshold for length?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to limit the email length to 50 characters:

```
df[df['email'].str.len()<51]
```

How to limit any string field to 50 characters:

```
df[df.applymap(lambda x: len(x) if isinstance(x, str) else 0).lt(51).all(axis=1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do a conditional on length like:

```
import pandas as pd
  
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv')
df = df[df['email'].map(len) < 20]
print(df.head)
```

Output:

```
email name  user
0  test1@hotmail.com  joe  4321
2    test-_2@aol.com  loy  6543>
```